# Always submit to server when editing in jqGrid, regardless of changes

Tags: javascript, ajax, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.1 in cell editing mode, and it's all working OK - when a user changes a cell value and hits Enter, the new value is submitted to the server as expected.

If a user enters a cell, does not change the value, and hits Enter, then the value is *not* submitted to the server, as expected.

For one of the columns though, I want the value to be sent to the server, even if it is not changed.

This seems to be the jqGrid code preventing this (from [saveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) method):

```
// The common approach is if nothing changed do not do anything
if (v2 !== $t.p.savedRow[fr].v){
```

So it's checking to see if the cell has changed, and if not does not continue to submit to the server.

Now, I could put in a nasty hack to the jqGrid source to change this, but I'd rather not edit jqGrid - is there some way I can get the desired behaviour using 'standard' jqGrid functionality?